# Lenovo laptop not turning on

Tags: laptop, power-supply, lenovo-laptop

My cousin's Lenovo 110 15ISK stopped woking after forgetting to unplug the charger after a long time, around 8 hours. Now it fails to turn on. No obvious response to charging, power button and no indicators lighting up. I tried basic touble shooting, like removing the battery and power cord and pressing the power button over 1 min etc. 
 I've checked the battery, multimeter reading shows 15.35v for a 14.4v battery, power cord is working. The area around the main power and battery connector on the board gets hot, temparature rises wih time. That's the only response I'm getting from the device. My tehnical knowledge of the thing is not too advanced but fairly good and therefore I'm a bit confused about further proceedings. I think the 'power circuit' is done for.
 Is there anything I may be able to do without taking it to a shop?
 Please hit me with some insights.
Thank Yo.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove cmos along with the battery
2. Power drain the unit 10-15 seconds
3. Plug in the power adapter
4. Turn on the unit with out the batteries connected

Here is a video on "Laptop does not power on or power up"
https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/videos/vid100760

please give me any feed back so i can try and give a better assist on this matter.